# Upgrading RavenDB from build 2910 to 3599 breaks API key authentication

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-studio

I have just upgraded my production database from build 2910 to build 3599 and it appears that the API Key authentication that was working previously is now broken.

Anonymous access is working when I go to studio without an API key because anonymous access is turned on. Before, if I attempted to connect to studio without an API key I'd get an Unauthorized error. Now, when I attempt to set AnonymousAccess to None then I get an "unauthorized" error although I'm passing the key that worked previously, before my upgrade.

In addition, other clients seem to be using the database fine (all CRUD operations) and it just seems to be studio.

Are there new settings I may be missing in the web.config (running in IIS mode)?

**UPDATE**

I am able to disable anonymous access and access the new Raven HTML 5 studio with my API key and a properly formatted URL. Is the Silverlight studio client broken in 3.0?

Comment: How did you disable anonymous access?

Comment: Set "Raven/AnonymousAccess" to "None"

Comment: That should work. Can you post the Fiddler output?